# Figure out this Four digit Palindrome with two distinct digits and

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

The sum of the digits of the palindrome is
Same as the number remaining after last two digits are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1881

Reasoning:

> Let's sat it's ABBA; then AB = A + B + B + A; 10A + B = 2A + 2B; 8A = B; A = 1, B = 8.

Comment: Got it..........